# make the torn paper to recover

Tags: opencv, graphics

I tear up one paper, and its fragments like :

[image: a torn paper]

and I want to make these fragments of the paper to recover.

I have done something by using opencv:

1. take pictures of these fragments and save them into computer disk
2. read each fragments and get their contour lines
3. calculate the similarity for each contour lines of the fragment
4. ???

What I should do if I want to recover these fragment to be one whole "paper" which like the paper don't tear up?

Any suggestions or methods would be appreciated, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is like a search problem; due to infinite numbers of states coming from number of numerous points and orientations, it is impossible to implement something like depth first search. You need a proper vision algorithm to reduce these number of states.

How did you compare the "contour lines" ? Where are these lines ? Your contours might be circular, and could have a very big number of "lines". You should look for ***"how can I create this contour, joining some parts of other contours"***

***"is this perimeter has a similarity with another one ? which part of the perimeters have highest similarity ?"***

Both of these questions yield to one solution that come to my mind, solving it human-way: Select a contour. Connect another one from some point. Rotate it until it hits. If there is a black space between, change the connection point. Try all points. If you find a connection point yielding to "no black space", connect these contours into one contour and continue the operation. If there exist no point, try another contour.

EDIT: Although this method does nothing but searching; it decreases the number of states with black space (contour finding) and hitting (coordinate comparison)

ENHANCEMENT: Use contour finding method with "simple approximation" (CV_APPROX_SIMPLE) to deduce the straight lines of the paper. You can then reduce the number of points you are going to try, by noting these points as paper sides.

EDIT2 : You may want to look at corner detection and stitching methods:

http://tobw.net/index.php?cat_id=2&project=Panorama%20Stitching%20Demo%20in%20Matlab,

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/introduction.html